# How to display MIDI data in real time to the GUI?

Tags: java, swing, midi, javasound

I have looked around for a bit but can't seem to figure out a solution to this. I am using the `javax.sound.midi` library to try print the current note(s) being played on the midi-device (just a MIDI piano).

I am a bit stumped. I am able to successfully locate and open my MIDI device. I have the sequencer and transmitter set but I'm not sure how to check for when a new note is played. I don't want to play something and have it saved as a file then played I want to check which key is being pressed in real-time. The end goal of this project was just to display different chords to the GUI (Swing) and then have it switch to a random chord after the correct chord (set of three or more notes played at once) is played on the MIDI device.

Currently, I have a swing GUI where a new chord is displayed every time a button is pressed, I want to change it so it shows a new chord when the chord is played on the midi-device (I'm not concerned with playback audio, just getting the note info).

Comment: What did you try so far?

Did you add a [ControllerEventListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/ControllerEventListener.html) already?

Please give a code example of what you tried to catch midi-change events with. In this question there should be enough info to start with: [Java Midi - ControllerEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228242/java-midi-controllereventlistener-how-to-change-the-instrument)

Comment: Duplicate of [Java getting input from MIDI keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937760/java-getting-input-from-midi-keyboard)